# vue project include htaccess file in dist

Tags: vue.js, webpack

The project was initialised with `vue init webpack`. It doesn't have a `public` directory.  I tried adding the `.htaccess` file at the same level as the `index.html` but it does not get included in the `dist` folder when I run `npm run build`

Comment: i might have solved it with https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin

Comment: also, looks like i should be upgrading to vue cli 3